# Generating a Unique ID by using Rand()

Tags: php, loops, random

Trying to create a ajax private chat. But can't seem to generate a unique ID that hasn't been used by another user.

```
    $genid    =   rand(1,999999999999);
    foreach($genid as &$rand){
    $q  =   mysql_query("SELECT ".$q_pchat." FROM users WHERE pchat_id1='".$rand."'");
    $r  =   mysql_num_rows($q);

        if($r == 0){
            $chatid =   $rand;
             break;
        }
 }
```

Get an internal server error 500. I think it's cause its an infinite loop.

Comment: Since you're already using MySQL, just use `SELECT UUID() as uniqid` in order to generate a truly unique identifier. Why bother with constructing your own, which is impractical, slow an doesn't even work?

Comment: If you really need PHP to generate it use uniqid() which generates a unique string.

Comment: @BenoîtLatinier - it doesn't generate anything unique, even the documentation says so - using a red background to highlight it's not unique in any way. However, like many people, I would welcome it if it really did generate a UUID/GUID.